# Bash running out of File Descriptors

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I was working on a project, and I want to contribute with the solution I found:

The code is of the kind:

```
while true
do
     while read VAR
     do
        ......
     done < <(find ........ | sort)
     sleep 3
done
```

The errors in the log where:

```
/dir/script.bin: redirection error: cannot duplicate fd: Too many open files
/dir/script.bin: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
/dir/script.bin: line 26: <(find "${DIRVAR}" -type f -name '*.pdf' | sort): Too many open files
find: `/somedirtofind': Too many open files
/dir/script.bin: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
/dir/script.bin: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
/dir/script.bin: line 26: <(find "${DIRVAR}" -type f -name '*.pdf' | sort): ambiguous redirect
```

I noticed with command:

`ls -l /proc/3657(pid here)/fd` that the file descriptors were constantly increasing.

Using Debian 7, GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me is:

```
while true
do
     find ........ | sort | while read VAR
     do
     done
     sleep 3
done
```

Which is, avoiding the subshell at the end, there must be some kind of leak.

Now I don't see file descriptors in the process directory when doing `ls`

Mail to bugtracker:

```
The minimum reproduceable code is:

#!/bin/bash
function something() {
  while true
  do
    while read VAR
    do
      dummyvar="a"
    done < <(find "/run/shm/directory" -type f | sort)
    sleep 3
  done
}
something &

Which fails with many pipes fd open.

Changing the While feed to this:

#!/bin/bash
function something() {
  find "/run/shm/directory" -type f | sort | while true
  do
    while read VAR
    do
      dummyvar="a"
    done
    sleep 3
  done
}
something &

Works completely normal.

However, removing the call as function in background:

#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  while read VAR
  do
    dummyvar="a"
  done < <(find "/run/shm/debora" -type f | sort)
  sleep 3
done

But executing the script with ./test.sh & (in background), works
without problems too.
```

Comment: Kind of just curious. What commands do you run in the loop? Do you break the loop before reading all data?

Comment: @konsolebox The most important part if the cat of PDFs into a single one. There are conditionals, sed, echos to a log, and a cat and echo to the same log. Then I delete the original PDFs

Comment: Do you run a process in the background?

Comment: @konsolebox yes, the while is contained in a function. The function is called in the same script in background, with &

Comment: @konsolebox there is the script if you want to take a look

Comment: Ok thanks. So far there's nothing unusual I see in it. Just odd how file descriptors are not recycled and reused.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. One reason to use `while...done < <(foo)` is because `foo` executes in a new process but the loop body will execute in the current process, hence the body can share variables with other code. With `foo | while ...done`, `foo` is in the current process and the loop body is in a new process, so any variables written by the body won't be visible elsewhere. Switching which part executes in which process may explain why file descriptors are/aren't cleaned up (when the subprocess exits)

Comment: @Warbo  I know this is old, but they replied me that it was fixed in Bash 4.3

Comment: @JorgeeFG I may have bumped into a regression in 5.0.17 as your workaround worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and played around with the things you suggested. You said:

> But executing the script with ./test.sh & (in background), works
> without problems too.

So what worked for me is to run in the background and just wait for it to finish each time:

```
while true
do
     while read VAR
     do
        ......
     done < <(find ........ | sort) &
     wait
done
```

Another thing that worked was to put the code creating the descriptor into a function without running on background:

```
function fd_code(){
     while read VAR
     do
        ......
     done < <(find ........ | sort)
}

while true
do
     fd_code
done
```